# Jquery append not showing div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create simple chat with ajax and PHP. From now i met a problem when i trying to show it in my HTML.

```
 [
    {"id_chat":1,"username":"admin","message":"ae","createddate":"2016-07-25"},
    {"id_chat":2,"username":"admin","message":"aeaee","createddate":"2016-07-25"}
 ]
```

Here is my script

```
function buka_pesan()
    {
        var username = '<?=$this->input->cookie('cookie_webstore_user')?>';
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?=base_url();?>chat/show_chat',
             success: function(data) {
                $.each(data.data, function(k, v) {
                    $(".direct_add").append("<div class='direct-chat-msg right'> " +
                        "<div class='direct-chat-info clearfix'>" +
                            "<span class='direct-chat-name pull-left'>" + data.username + "</span>" +
                            "<span class='direct-chat-timestamp pull-right'>" + data.createddate + "</span>" +
                        "</div>" +
                        "<div class='direct-chat-text'> "+
                                data.message+
                         "</div>"+
                    "</div>");
                });
             }
        });
    }   


    $(window).load(function() {
    buka_pesan();
    var username = '<?=$this->input->cookie('cookie_webstore_user')?>';
    $("#send_msg").click(function(){

        if($("#pesannya").val() == '')
        {
            alert('Isi pesannya dulu kak');
        }else
        {

            $.ajax({
                 url: '<?=base_url();?>chat/savechat',
                 data: {pesannya:$("#pesannya").val()},
                 type: 'POST',
                 dataType: 'JSON',
                  success: function(data) {
                        buka_pesan();
                     }
                });
        }
            }); 

});
```

and here is my form

```
<div class="direct-chat-messages">
                    <div class="direct_add"> </div>
                 <div class="box-footer">
                  <form action="#" id="form_id" method="post">
                   <div class="col-sm-5"> <div class="input-group">
                      <input type="text" id="pesannya"  name="pesan" class="form-control">
                          <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button type="button" id="send_msg" onclick="buka_pesan();" class="btn btn-warning btn-flat">Send</button>
                          </span>
                    </div>
                    </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <!-- /.box-footer-->
              </div>
```

So, i want to show the recent chat. But no help. with my script above it's i only can see submit button. Any solution ?

Comment: why are you doing 2 ajax calls?

Comment: the first ajax is for showing recent message and the second one is for saving message

Comment: why not load recent messages at page load?

Comment: well, i don't  know why i do that. It just out from my mind.

Comment: lol man good one :)))

Answer (score 2):

Change `data` with `v`

```
$.each(data, function(k, v) {
    $(".direct_add").append("<div class='direct-chat-msg right'> " +
      "<div class='direct-chat-info clearfix'>" +
      "<span class='direct-chat-name pull-left'>" + v.username + "</span>" +
      "<span class='direct-chat-timestamp pull-right'>" + v.createddate + "</span>" +
      "</div>" +
      "<div class='direct-chat-text'> " +
      v.message +
      "</div>" +
      "</div>");
  });
```

Comment: i still cant see any recen chat

Comment: are your ajax calls working,do you have any console errors?

Comment: from buka pesan i get this : `[{"id_chat":1,"username":"admin","message":"1","createddate":"2016-07-25"},{"id_chat":2,"username":"admin","message":"2","createddate":"2016-07-25"},{"id_chat":3,"username":"admin","message":"3","createddate":"2016-07-25"},{"id_chat":4,"username":"admin","message":"4","createddate":"2016-07-25"},{"id_chat":5,"username":"admin","message":"ae","createddate":"2016-07-25"}]`. I use firebug. i cant see any error

Comment: i think you don't have a data attribute to your data change `data.data` to `data` only

Comment: then what i need to do ? should i change the ajax result ?

Comment: how does console.log(data) look like in the `buka_pesan` function?